# Is there a way to shoot a ranged weapon consistently without moving my feet?

Tags: diablo-ii

I switched to using a bow, and now I find myself constantly running to a few steps away from enemies before shooting them in the face.  At my current level it isn't a big deal since I can still tank most of them, but as I face tougher enemies they are often dealing some painful blows.  I try to just stand at range and fire, but soon my toon is running back into the fray because I accidentally missed when attempting to click an enemy.  Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but... I *think* you can hold shift and click.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you hold shift, your character will never take a step, instead being forced to perform whatever action is bound to your mouse when clicking. This is useful for casting spells or attacking at range without risking running directly into the fray.

So... <kbd>Shift</kbd> + click.

Comment: Sweet! That is what I needed.

Comment: It also works quite well for melee attacks, when you want to wait on a large horde of enemies to approach you.  My paladin used it all the time.

Comment: @Kexlox Somehow in the early days of the internet, I knew all this stuff.  Now I am cursed to know it is possible, but not be able to figure out how, without help :).  I played so much Torchlight it is hard to keep it all straight though.